# Which format to provide a report template to a client?

Tags: template-design, microsoft-word

I have this report template we made fo a client. Keeping in mind the client specifically asked for it to be editable, I did a relatively simple design, yet with some nice details to make it appear a bit more interesting.

However, now I'm struggling with the format to deliver. I was thinking of Word, but page numbering is tricky since I did some nice pagination element which I think is impossible to achieve in MS Word. Client says they could use EPS, but the problem I see is they won't have automatic pagination like you can have in Word (I admit I rarely use it, so I'm quite ignorant on everything Word). Client specifically mentioned they can't edit PDF files, and obviously InDesign is a no go for the client.

Is there a format I can use that the user can edit? Or an option to make custom pagination work on Word, like applying "CSS like" styles? I think not, but maybe I'm missing something obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the client needs Word, send a word file, if he uses something else, uses something else.

Designing is not presenting something "nice" but not usable. Design studies the real needs of a project, in this case, usability.

If pagination is your only concern, either skip that part or talk to the client about the limitations of that specific feature.

---

You can explore the use of Scribus, but it needs capacitation which is an expense that has probably no sense for one specific task.

And of course, you could program some CMS system online... but again, it has probably little purpose.

Comment: It seems to me that the first part of your answer has nothing to do with the question and is out of place. I am very aware of the usability problems, therefore, I ask. If I had wanted advice about UX, I would have asked my question in a completely different way. I am aware that I do not know everything and there could be something that I am missing, especially on a deadline on a Friday afternoon. The second part is more sensible, since we are already doing what you say: to create a small script inside the CMS. Now we have usability, speed and control without renouncing aesthetics.

Comment: What I mean on the first part is that the usability takes priority over design, and probably over features.

And regarding the pagination, probably you could share a screenshot so what you designed can be actually implemented in Word.